# Visual Studio "Clean Solution" deletes custom file

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project that uses an XML-File where the user can store custom configuration options. This file is parsed when the corresponding configuration class is instantiated.

The file is placed in the root-level of the project folder. In the solution explorer, the build action is set to *Content* and the copy option is set to *Copy if newer*.

My problem: When I use *Clean Solution* or *Clean Project*, that file gets deleted by Visual Studio. Since the file was not created during the build process, but rather by me, I believe this should not happen. What setting do I have to change, so that the file stays untouched?

This **only** happens if I executed the project. If I directly choose *Clean Project* without building it beforehand (there are no auto-generated files in the root folder), everything behaves as it should.

I tried:

- referencing the file in *Resources.resx*
- commiting the file in Git (which at least allows me to restore the file after it was deleted)
- renaming the file (believing that the initial file name might have coincided with  some magic file that might be auto-generated)
- searching online for a solution (most questions are about Visual Studio **NOT** cleaning all files)